# Set height and width of image inside div using javascript and jquery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

I have a problem were I want to set the height and width of image inside the div using only Javascript and JQuery.

Here is my code:

```
<div class="myGallery">
    <img class="replaced" src="myimage.jpg" style="display: inline;">
</div>

.myGallery {
    display: table-cell;
    height: 220px;
    text-align: center !important;
    vertical-align: middle !important;
    width: 110px;
}

.myGallery img {
    text-align: center;
    vertical-align: middle;
    width: auto !important;
}


function ChangeHW(hdnValue)
{

    if (hdnValue==1)
    {
        //i want to remove height and width attribute of image
            //this is working..
            $('div.myGallery > img').removeAttr('width');
            $('div.myGallery > img').removeAttr('height');
    }
    else
    {
        //i want to set height and width attribute of image 
            //this is not working..i cant set width-height using this line od code
            $('div.myGallery > img').css('width', '110px');
            $('div.myGallery > img').css('height', '220px');
    }

}
```

Any ideas?

Answer (score 2):

Attributes are different than style. Say your current image tag looks like this:

```
<img src="foo.png" width="200" height="200" />
```

After `$('div.myGallery > img').removeAttr('width')`, it will look like this:

```
<img src="foo.png" height="200" />
```

You are removing the width *attribute*. Now after `$('div.myGallery > img').css('width', '440px')`, it'll look like this:

```
<img src="foo.png" height="200" style="width: 440px;" />
```

You're adding in width, but it's the CSS style and not the attribute. Try this instead:

```
$('div.myGallery > img').attr('width', '440');
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

```
$('div.myGallery > img').css('width', '110px !important');

$('div.myGallery > img').css('height', '220px !important');
```

Answer (score 1):

This is a function to fit an image to 586x586 div tag.

```
function img_fit(img_id){

    var img_width = $("#"+img_id).width();
    var img_height= $("#"+img_id).height();
    var max_side = Math.max(img_width, img_height);
    var top = 0, left = 0, scale = 0;
    var new_width, new_height,new_scale;
    scale = (max_side == img_height)? img_height/586 : img_width/586;

    if(max_side == img_height){
         new_width = img_width / scale;
         new_height = 586;
         top = 0;
         left = Math.round((586 - new_width)/2);
         $("#"+img_id).animate({
            'width':new_width,
            'height':new_height, 
            'top':0,
            'left':left,
            'duration':300
        });
         //$("#"+img_id).width(new_width);
         //$("#"+img_id).height(586);
         new_scale = 586*scale/img_height;
    }
    else{
        new_height  = img_height / scale;
        new_width = 586;
        top = Math.round((586 - new_height)/2);
        //top = 0;
        left = 0;
        $("#"+img_id).animate({
            'width':new_width,
            'height':new_height, 
            'top':top,
            'left':0,
            'duration':300
        });

    }

}
```

Answer (score 0):

You look to be setting the image width larger than the containing div, could that be the problem?

Yo remove the height and width `removeAttr` would work if it was set in the image tag `<img src="puppies.jpg" width="100" height="100">`, otherwise, to change it in the css, I would set `width` and `height = auto`, or if you want the container to determine the size try something like  `width:100% height:auto`. 
To add height and width your `.css('width','440px')` should work. However as mentioned the containing div is smaller.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe this could help:

```
.newCssClass { height : 110px !important; width : 440px !important; }

$("div.myGallery img").addClass("newCssClass");
```